# Silent notification - ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm building an app and I have created a method to detect if the user has new pictures in his photo librery throw `ALAssetsLibrary`, the method works fine.

I want to run this method from time to time to check for new pictures. If the user has new pictures, to notify him by a notificaiton.

I'm searching for a trigger to activate this method from time to time while the app is in background state or not running at all.
I know by sending a silent notification in ios 7, I can activate the app on the background state.

1. Once a silent notification is received , can I activate the method somehow? or the silent notoficaiton is just for receiving data and update the app.
2. Do you think of any other way that I can activate this function without the user will know about it ?

Comment: Have you tried with NSTimer?

Comment: Does NsTimer works while the app is in not running state?

Comment: I'm not sure but I guess that it might be possible if not by default then by setting up some property :)

Comment: Do you know anything about silent notifications and ability to activate a method throw them?

Comment: I have read something about ib but I haven't played with them yet

Answer (score 0):

Not Possible currently!

1- When a silent notification is received the app is only intended to upload/download data hence we can only work with `NSURLSessionTask`. Access to other API's which require asynchronous blocks to execute like `ALAssetLibrary` is not available.

2- No other option of scanning library without the user knowing. You can display a notification to User and then on User's discretion app can be launched to perform desired scanning.